# Electric field theorical value at an equipotential on a surface with conductivity

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, surface-diffusion

I'm not well versed in electrostatics and had this question no one could help me with (even after searching on the internet) : I have a surface (with its resistance increasing by 1kohm per centimeter²) and I have an electric battery (EB) with voltage 9V and intensity 2A connected to it at A (+) and B (-).

Elsewhere, on the surface, I have two electrodes C and D at a known distance of A. I want to know how far I will measure something (i.e. more than 0.001V) in C (the potential in C, or the difference of potentials between C and D) i.e. I'd like to know which formula to use linking "distance A-C", "conductivity of the surface", "voltage and intensity of the input current" and "current in C" (wanted).

You will find an attached picture to clarify my question : [image]

Comment: What do you mean by intensity of battery = 2A?

Comment: for instance on aliexpress there are power supplies with description "1A / 2A / 3A / 5A / 6A / 8A Switch Power Adapter
Input Voltage:  AC100V-240V
Output Voltage: DC 5V 12V 24V
Output Current: 1A~5A"
(and so i'm using a battery with specs voltage=9V, current=2A)